# ListItem imageChanging not working properly in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listitem, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView`,I am having a custom ListItem designed for it having some `TextView`'s and an `ImageView`. I want to change that particular image when clicked . I have tried but when i click on that image from `ListView`, the below listItem's image is changing.

For example if i click on 0th position image then image is changing of 1st position ListIem and when i scroll up and down the List,it changes randomly.

I dont know what is happening with it,I have used notifydatasetChanged on my adapter,But its not working,My code is as below.

Please help me,Thank you,

**Code**

```
 private class RssAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> {
        private List<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> rssFeedLst;
        int selectedPosition;

        public RssAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> rssFeedLst) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, rssFeedLst);
            this.rssFeedLst = rssFeedLst;
            Boolean addtoShotlist;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = View.inflate(HotelListActivity.this, R.layout.list_row,
                        null);

                rssHolder = new RssHolder();
                rssHolder.iv_add = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_add);
                rssHolder.rssTitleView = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                rssHolder.tv_offer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ofr);
                rssHolder.rssImagHotel = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.hotelImage);
                rssHolder.rssImageHotelRate = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.rateHotel2);
                rssHolder.rssHotelPrice = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textHotelRate);
                rssHolder.rssHotelAddress = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textHotelDesc);
                // rssHolder.adres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adres);
                // rssHolder.rssHotelRating = (TextView)
                // view.findViewById(R.id.textHotelRating);
                rssHolder.rating_hotel = (RatingBar) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.rateHotelImage);
                rssHolder.tv_currcode = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_currcode);

                view.setTag(rssHolder);

            } else {
                rssHolder = (RssHolder) view.getTag();

            }

            final RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult rssFeed = rssFeedLst
                    .get(position);

            rssHolder.rssTitleView.setText(rssFeed.getName());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(rssFeed.getHotel_image(),
                    rssHolder.rssImagHotel);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage_rating(rssFeed.getHote_rate_image(),
                    rssHolder.rssImageHotelRate);

            rssHolder.rssHotelPrice.setText(rssFeed.getHotel_price());

            rssHolder.rssHotelAddress.setText(rssFeed.getHotel_desc());
            rssHolder.rating_hotel.setRating(Float.valueOf(rssFeed
                    .getHotel_rate()));
            rssHolder.tv_currcode.setText(Consts.currencyCode);
            if (rssFeed.getoffer() != null) {
                rssHolder.tv_offer.setText("**" + rssFeed.getoffer() + "**");
            } else {
                rssHolder.tv_offer.setText("");
            }

            rssHolder.iv_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    try {

                        if (position == selectedPosition) {

                            rssHolder.iv_add
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);

                        } else {

                            rssHolder.iv_add
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus12);
                        }

                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    System.out
                            .println("::::::::::::My data in side hotel List activity:::::::::;"
                                    + position
                                    + ""
                                    + rssFeed.getName()
                                    + "\n"
                                    + rssFeed.getHotel_price());

                    /*
                     * RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult rssFeed1 = rssFeedLst
                     * .get(position);
                     */

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey i am unable to find this java file in your project please tell me the name of java file so that it is easy me to find it.

Comment: @SurenderKumar-Hello,You got it or not?

Comment: @SurenderKumar-hi code you got?

Comment: Yah i got that code but the java file that contains this code was unadble to find.

Comment: It lis "HotelListActiviyt.java"

Comment: Please tell me if you got it,

Comment: Yes man i got your project .

Comment: i am telling about "java" class you are asking about

Comment: oh... yah.. i also get that java file

Comment: ohk..sir..Can you Please see it and help me to solve it out..Actually its an image to add to favourite and add to list to display as favourites and we can alos remove it on clicking it again

Comment: @SurenderKumar-hello,are you getting me?

Comment: Yes , i am getting you and i am working over it, whenever i find solution i ll let you know.

Comment: @SurenderKumar-hello.you there?

Comment: Yes , actually i had partially done, i am using two imageview one over another and on image click showing and hiding imageviews but its showing and hiding randomly images.

Comment: same problem you are facing..!!!

Comment: I don't know why it is behaving strange changing alternate images.

Comment: @SurenderKumar-even i dontk know thats why i have asked question

Comment: Its now totally funny...:P

Comment: I am working on it because i don;t know why its happening so don't depend on me if i get solution i ll tell you.

Comment: i am also trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For notify data-set changed your calling the wrong method the correct method is `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: you dont need to call notifyDataSetChanged from within your onClick when you change the image..notifyDataSetChanged has to be called when the data in your List<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> rssFeedLst gets modified probably from your activity

Answer (score 0):

1.) Write this code inside your custom adapter getView :

```
if (position == selectedPosition) {

            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);

        } else {

            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
        }
```

2.) Make a method in custom adapter :

```
public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }

//where selectPosition is private int selectedPosition = -1;
```

3.) Call this method from activity listitem  click like :

```
   ((Category_Adapter) adapter).setSelected(position);
            listview.invalidate();
```

4. Make sure your listview set to single choice mode.

Comment: hello,thank you for response,I want to change imagebackground when it is clicked.I am not getting you sir,Please help me,What is selectedPosition,

Comment: select_position is the varibale declared at top of adapter and tells the current list position.

Comment: And put the 1st code inside your imageclick listener and change backgound.

Comment: I had edited your code and posted so check the edited things.

Comment: hi..There is no change in my list now..:(

Comment: Actually whats happening after putting code which block is executing from if-else.

Comment: image is not changing now,It was changing before.

Comment: Ok share it, let see can i do something or not.

Comment: send it to my mail id

Comment: sonu.surendra0@gmail.com

Comment: sent an email,Please check sir

Answer (score 0):

```
private class RssAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> {
        private List<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> rssFeedLst;
       private int selectedPosition =-1;// initalize position

        public RssAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult> rssFeedLst) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, rssFeedLst);
            this.rssFeedLst = rssFeedLst;
            Boolean addtoShotlist;
        }
//make this method
public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = View.inflate(HotelListActivity.this, R.layout.list_row,
                        null);

                rssHolder = new RssHolder();
                rssHolder.iv_add = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_add);
                rssHolder.rssTitleView = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                rssHolder.tv_offer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ofr);
                rssHolder.rssImagHotel = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.hotelImage);
                rssHolder.rssImageHotelRate = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.rateHotel2);
                rssHolder.rssHotelPrice = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textHotelRate);
                rssHolder.rssHotelAddress = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.textHotelDesc);
                // rssHolder.adres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adres);
                // rssHolder.rssHotelRating = (TextView)
                // view.findViewById(R.id.textHotelRating);
                rssHolder.rating_hotel = (RatingBar) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.rateHotelImage);
                rssHolder.tv_currcode = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_currcode);

                view.setTag(rssHolder);

            } else {
                rssHolder = (RssHolder) view.getTag();

            }

            final RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult rssFeed = rssFeedLst
                    .get(position);

            rssHolder.rssTitleView.setText(rssFeed.getName());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(rssFeed.getHotel_image(),
                    rssHolder.rssImagHotel);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage_rating(rssFeed.getHote_rate_image(),
                    rssHolder.rssImageHotelRate);

            rssHolder.rssHotelPrice.setText(rssFeed.getHotel_price());

            rssHolder.rssHotelAddress.setText(rssFeed.getHotel_desc());
            rssHolder.rating_hotel.setRating(Float.valueOf(rssFeed
                    .getHotel_rate()));
            rssHolder.tv_currcode.setText(Consts.currencyCode);
            if (rssFeed.getoffer() != null) {
                rssHolder.tv_offer.setText("**" + rssFeed.getoffer() + "**");
            } else {
                rssHolder.tv_offer.setText("");
            }

            rssHolder.iv_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //remove selectposition = position

                    try {

                        if (position == selectedPosition) {

                            rssHolder.iv_add
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fill);

                        } else {

                            rssHolder.iv_add
                                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus12);
                        }

                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    System.out
                            .println("::::::::::::My data in side hotel List activity:::::::::;"
                                    + position
                                    + ""
                                    + rssFeed.getName()
                                    + "\n"
                                    + rssFeed.getHotel_price());

                    /*
                     * RSSFeed_SelectedHotelResult rssFeed1 = rssFeedLst
                     * .get(position);
                     */

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Finally call adapter selected method from activity listitem click and set position.